# How to get a query from a different notebook in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

My first post here ever :)
So I am having a problem :/
Working with `Databricks (db)`
I know how to execute a different notebook in db using the `%run`
But I have two questions:

1. Notebook 1 has a single query and notebook 2 has a function that needs that query, how do I input that query over there? I tried only the `%run` and it runs the query I tried defining it to a variable, tried to pass it as a parameter to the function and nothing worked :( (but putting the query in the function it does work!!)
2. Is it possible to have a notebook full of queries, in different cells, and call a specific cell? I tried to look it up but I couldn’t find it anywhere :/

Thank you so much!!
Have a nice year :)

I tried only the `%run` and it runs the query I tried defining it to a variable, tried to pass it as a parameter to the function and nothing worked :( (but putting the query in the function it does work!!)

Comment: For Q2 what about changing each cell to a different Python function: def mycell1function():  Then you %run the notebook with the functions. Then from your parent notebook you call the functions you need.

Comment: Could you please add to the post whatever you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Notebook 1 has a single query and notebook 2 has a function that needs that query, how to I input that query over there? I tried only
>    the %run and it runs the query I tried defining it to a variable,
>    tried to pass it as a parameter to the function and nothing worked :(
>    (but putting the query in the function it does work!!)

Calling the Notebook from another Notebook using `dbuitls.notebook.run()` is the solution for it.

Pass your query to another Notebook as parameter like below. Then use
`myquery=dbutils.widgets.get("query")` to get that parameter value and you can use that in Called notebook function like a sample demonstration below.

**`Nb1`- Calling Notebook:**

[image]

**`Nb2`- Called Notebook with function executed**

[image]

Here use `eval()` to execute your query in the function.

> 2. Is it possible to have a notebook full of queries, in different cells, and call a specific cell? I tried to look it up but I couldn’t
>    find it anywhere :/

**AFAIK**, we cannot call particular cell from a Notebook to another Notebook.

Using functions for each cell and call it using `%run Notebook_name` as suggested by **@GregGalloway** in comments can be a workaround for it.

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Q1) I would follow the documentation in here using the command, where notebook-name is the notebook you're calling

`results = dbutils.notebook.run("notebook-name", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2", ...})`

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html

Q2) I don't think this is possible, I would suggest splitting out the code into another notebook with only the code you want called